# CRS dialog no longer opening

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm new to QGIS, so supect this is trivial, but it has frustrated me for the last hour or more... Last week whenever I added a csv as a layer once I'd filled in the first dialog it automatically opened a dialog where I could select the correct CRS. Today when I open a CSV file I go straight from the open CSV dialog to the map with a warning flagged at the top that the CRS was not set so it has used the default value, which is wrong. I must have somehow clicked some setting somewhere that has turned off the (very handy!) dialog and I can't find it anywhere. What have I done wrong and how can I get QGIS to automatically open the dialog again?

Comment: You can always set the layer CRS by right-clicking on the layer and selecting **Set Layer CRS**. Ofcourse this doesn't answer your question, just a little tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option here which should prompt users for a CRS when adding a new layer via:

*Settings* > *Options* > *CRS*

[image: CRS options]

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was exactly it. I've not seen that box before, so puzzled about how I turned this off, but nevermind.

Comment: Awesome! And don't worry, sometimes QGIS likes to play games with users :)